# How to loop over a dict and a list together in ansible?

Tags: ansible

Say I have two variable like these:

```
dict:
  key1: val1
  key2: val2
list:
  - item1
  - item2
```

Can I loop over these two variables like below?

```
- shell: echo {{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}
  with_dict: "{{ dict }}"
  with_items: "{{ list }}"
```

I have no idea to loop over these two variables together and don't wanna change the data type of the variables. Is there any way to achieve this kind of loop in ansible?

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-parallel-sets-of-data

Answer (score 0):

The [combine](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter that is introduced in Ansible 2.0 appears to be the closest thing to what you need, but I don't know if it will merge a dict & a list or just two dicts.

Your might need to write your own custom [lookup plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins) in order to merge these two different variable types.